# How to write to delta table/delta format in Python without using Pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delta-lake

I am looking for a way to write back to a delta table in python without using pyspark. I know there is a library called deltalake/[delta-lake-reader](https://pypi.org/project/delta-lake-reader/) that can be used to read delta tables and convert them to pandas dataframes.

**The goal is to write back to the opened delta table**

The input code looks like this:

```
from deltalake import DeltaTable
dt = DeltaTable('path/file')
df = dt.to_pandas()
```

So is there any way to get something like this to write from a pandas dataframe back to a delta table:

```
df = pandadf.to_delta()
DeltaTable.write(df, 'path/file')
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: it's not yet possible if you look into features matrix: https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs#features

Answer (score 14):

Now it is supported !!!, see this example

```
import duckdb 
from deltalake.writer import write_deltalake
df =duckdb.sql('''
LOAD 'httpfs';
SELECT countries_and_territories, sum(deaths) as total FROM 
read_parquet('https://pandemicdatalake.blob.core.windows.net/public/curated/covid-19/ecdc_cases/latest/ecdc_cases.parquet')
group by 1
order by total desc
limit 5;
''').df()
write_deltalake('Pathto/covid', df,mode='append')
```

Comment: Mim is correct! To provide additional context, they are using the [`delta-rs`](https://delta-io.github.io/delta-rs/python/) library which does not have a spark dependency. You can install delta-rs with pip or conda:

`$ pip install deltalake` or `$ conda install -c conda-forge delta-spark`

Answer (score 1):

@Mim is correct. This just provides more info.

Currently, you can use [delta-rs](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs) to read and write to Delta Lake directly.

You can install by `pip install deltalake` or `conda install -c conda-forge delta-spark`.

```py
import pandas as pd
from deltalake.writer import write_deltalake

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3]})
write_deltalake("path/to/delta-tables/table1", df)
```

### Writing to S3

```py
storage_options = {
    "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION": "us-west-2",
    "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "xxx",
    "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "xxx",
    "AWS_S3_ALLOW_UNSAFE_RENAME": "true",
}

write_deltalake(
    "s3a://my-bucket/delta-tables/table1",
    df,
    mode="append",
    storage_options=storage_options,
)
```

To remove `AWS_S3_ALLOW_UNSAFE_RENAME` and concurrently write, needs to set up [DynamoDB lock](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/tree/main/dynamodb_lock).

Follow [this GitHub ticket](https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/issues/1091) for more updates regarding how to set up correctly.