# DataFrame pandas to Delta format without spark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, delta-lake

I have a dataframe in pandas and I need to transfer it to delta format without using spark.

I searched a lot about this but I didn't find any solution that doesn't use spark.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3],"y": [3, 2, 1]})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write to delta table/delta format in Python without using Pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69407302/how-to-write-to-delta-table-delta-format-in-python-without-using-pyspark)

Comment: this command returned me a parquet file and a folder called _delta_log with a json inside

Comment: Delta table is not a file format, it a layer which stores the data in parquet format and keys track of all the action of the data in a log folder.

Comment: I can confirm that parquet with a json is the structure of data in delta format - arudsekaberne is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The [delta-rs](https://delta-io.github.io/delta-rs/python/) library does not have a spark dependency. You can save your pandas DataFrame as a Delta Table the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
from deltalake.writer import write_deltalake

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3],"y": [3, 2, 1]})
write_deltalake('/path/to/save/delta/table', df)
```

To install the delta-rs library, you can use pip:

```
$ pip install deltalake
```

Or you can use conda:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge delta-spark
```